# QListWidgetItem pointer causes program to crash

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

In my program I have a series of tabs and won each tab there is a combo box and `QListWidget`. I am trying to read the status of the items on the `QListWidget` through a pointer of type `QListWidgetItem`. The program crashes at this point of the code. Im sure the program crashes here since I double checked it with breakpoints.

This is my code;

```
void MainWindow::on_applyButton_clicked()
{
//Reset list
MainWindow::revenueList.clear();
QStringList itemList;
itemList <<"Revenue growth" << "Cost of revenue growth" << "Operating income growth"
        << "Net income growth" << "Total operating expense growth" << "Gross profit"
        << "Operating profit" << "Net profit";

//Processing income statement
//Loop through all itemsin ComboBox
int items = ui->inc_st_comb->count();

for(int currentItem = 0; currentItem < items; currentItem++)
{
    //Set to current index
    ui->inc_st_comb->setCurrentText(itemList.at(currentItem));

    //Point to QListWidget Item and read checkbox
    QListWidgetItem *listItem = ui->inc_st_list->item(currentItem);

    if(listItem->checkState() == Qt::Checked)
    {
        MainWindow::revenueList.append(true);
    }
    else if (listItem->checkState() == Qt::Unchecked)
    {
        MainWindow::revenueList.append(false);
    }
}

    qDebug() << "U: " << MainWindow::revenueList;
}
```

The program crashes at this block;

```
if(listItem->checkState() == Qt::Checked)
 {
      MainWindow::revenueList.append(true);
 }
 else if (listItem->checkState() == Qt::Unchecked)
 {
      MainWindow::revenueList.append(false);
 }
```

This is probably because the pointer `listItem` points to a invalid location or `NULL`. How do I go about this problem? Am I coding something wrong?

Comment: "This is probably because the pointer listItem points to a invalid location or NULL." Probably? Why not verify this in your debugger before posting on SO? Figure out the _exact_ problem first.

Comment: Can you explain me how to do this on debugger? I am new to Qt programming. Learning myself. Any advice would be helpful?

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight you didn't have to down vote my question. I solved my issue and posted the answer. Please check other answers before acting.

Comment: I did downvote (you were right to guess that) - [ask] says **Help others reproduce the problem** and your incomplete test case doesn't do that.  *Solving your issue* is one good outcome; however, the real value of a question and answer is how useful it is to future visitors seeking help with a similar problem.  It's up to you whether to take a downvote as a personal slight; I've had some, and it usually indicates that I haven't been as helpful as I could.  Don't forget that ten minutes improving your [mcve] is many hours saved by potential answerers who could help you!

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed my error; 
The part I was doing wrong was that I was trying to access the items on `QListWidget` using the value returned by `QComboBox::count()` function.
The number of items inside the combo box was 8; but the number items on on this `QListWidget` for a given `QComboBox` selection was 3. I solved by adding a another for loop to loop through the items on the `QListWidget` by limiting the loop count using `QListWidget::count()`.

Here is my working code;

```
void MainWindow::on_applyButton_clicked()
{
//Reset list
MainWindow::revenueList.clear();
QStringList itemList;
itemList <<"Revenue growth" << "Cost of revenue growth" << "Operating income growth"
        << "Net income growth" << "Total operating expense growth" << "Gross profit"
        << "Operating profit" << "Net profit";

//Processing income statement
//Loop through all itemsin ComboBox
int items = ui->inc_st_comb->count();

for(int currentItem = 0; currentItem < items; currentItem++)
{
    //Set to current index
    ui->inc_st_comb->setCurrentText(itemList.at(currentItem));

    for(int index = 0; index < ui->inc_st_list->count(); index++)
    {
         //Point to QListWidget Item and read checkbox
         QListWidgetItem *listItem = ui->inc_st_list->item(index);


         if(listItem->checkState() == Qt::Checked)
         {
             MainWindow::revenueList.append(true);
         }
         else if (listItem->checkState() == Qt::Unchecked)
         {
             MainWindow::revenueList.append(false);
         }
    }
}

   qDebug() << "U: " << MainWindow::revenueList;
}
```